# Android Studio is not running Deploy as Instant App

Tags: android-instant-apps

I have just upgraded Android Studio to 2022.2.1 Patch 1. I have a configuration to Deploy as Instant App. It worked this morning but since upgrading it won't deploy it. I hit the "run" button and it says "launching on Pixel XL" but never does anything from there. I have my app set up to do instant app deployments. Any suggestions would be deeply appreciated.

I edited my configuration with "Deploy as Instant App" checked. But when I hit run it doesn't run on either an emulator nor on my pixel phone.

Comment: Hi there. Same issue here! Spent hours yesterday to understand what is happening. I run the app as instant, the build is perfect but nothing happens on the phone. In Android studio the logs are empty, nothing not error no warning nothing at all.

Comment: After the Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 update I'm having the same issue

Comment: Did yall attempt to invalidate cache & restart and try on other devices and emulators? Sometimes android studio can be buggy and be fixed after clearing caches.